# How to make a client / server connection using Rserver and Windows Server 2008

Tags: r

I am searching for a robust solution to perform extensive computations on a remote server, dedicated to computational tasks. The server is on Windows 2008 R2 and has R x64 3.4.1 installed on it. I've searched for free solutions and am now focusing on the Rserver/RSclient packages solutions.
However, I can't connect any client (using RSclient) to the instanced server.

This is how I'm proceeding at the moment from the server side:

```
library(Rserve)
run.Rserve(config.file = "Rserv.conf")
```

using the following Rserv.conf file:

```
port 6311
remote enable
plaintext enable
control enable
r-control enable
```

The server is now intanciated using the Rsession (It's a bit ugly, but will change that latter on):

```
running Rserve in this R session (pid=...), 1 server(s)
```

Now, i'm trying to connect using a remote computer (Client-side) using:

```
library(RSclient)
c = RS.connect(host = "...")
```

The connection then seems to succeed, checking for c:

```
> c
Rserve QAP1 connection 0x000000000fbe9f50 (socket 764, queue length 0)
```

The error occurs when i try to eval anything, for example:

```
> RS.server.eval(c,"0<1")
Error in RS.server.eval(c, "0<1") : command failed with status code 0x4e: no control line present (control commands disabled or server shutdown)
```

I've read the available guides but still failed in connecting. What is wrong? It seems to be related to control lines but I authorized them in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

for me the problem was solved by initiating the Rserve instance with the command:

```
R CMD Rserve --RS-port 9000 --RS-enable-remote --RS-enable-control
```

instead of starting it in the R environment (`library(Rserve), run.Rserve(config.file = "Rserv.conf")`). You may try this on Windows as well.

Answer (score 0):

Refer https://github.com/s-u/Rserve/wiki/rserve.conf.

```
port 6311
remote enable -> it should be remote true
plaintext enable
control enable
r-control enable
```

Likewise refer the link and try with actual values